# What does Django do between authentication and view dispatch?

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I am trying to diagnose some performance issues I'm having with Django (3.2.18), Graphene (2.1.8), and Graphene-Django (2.14.0) using datadog. I'm also using gunicorn as my web server and postgres as my db.

When looking at the trace for some oddly long-running requests, I'm seeing that there is a long delay between when the `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` call completes and when my view class gets `setup` and `dispatch` is called. This delay can sometimes take as long as 20 seconds but most of the time takes 10s of milliseconds.

Unfortunately, datadog is not giving me any additional insight into what is happening between the authenticate call and the dispatch as can be seen in this screenshot of a trace.

[image]

I don't think this is an issue where I'm running out of gunicorn workers because I'm assuming that a worker already has possession of the request in order to perform the authentication logic but I'm happy to be corrected about a bad assumption.

Any pointers as to what might be happening here would be greatly appreciated as I'm not really sure where to begin looking.